# Can we use PHP function strtotime in Mysql Query

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

I have the following MySQL syntax which gives me an error.

I am aware that you cannot compare date variables directly, so I use `strtotime` to create a Unix timestamp to compare dates.

Can you use the PHP `strtotime` function within a MySQL query?

```
$result = select * from table where strtotime(Date) >= strtotime($_POST[DateFrom1])  
&& strtotime(Date) <= strtotime($_POST[DateTo1])";
```

Comment: That's no right PHP! And no, it isn't possible to convert MySQL-tablefields from string to time with PHP.

Comment: What makes you think you can't simply compare date fields directly in mysql? You can, so long as the column type is `date` or `datetime` or other date related type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is `NOT` a valid PHP syntax. Code below is a clean and proper way of doing this:

```
$from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["DateFrom1"]));
$to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST["DateTo1"]));
$query = "select * from table where date between '$from' and '$to'";
// use this query to your mysqli
```

Answer (score 7):

Your code must be this:

```
$result = "select * from table 
              where unix_timestamp(Date) >= unix_timestamp(".$_POST[DateFrom1].")  
&& unix_timestamp(Date) <= unix_timestamp(".$_POST[DateTo1].")";
```

To convert date in timestamp in mysql there is function `unix_timestamp`.

Comment: + for unix_timestamp()

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to use the mysql function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

So maybe something along the lines of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) >= '" . strtotime($_POST[DateFrom1]) . "' && UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) <= '" . strtotime($_POST[DateTo1]) . "';";
```

Better yet would be to use [Named Placeholders](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Named_Placeholders) and PDO.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=whateverHost;dbname=yourDB;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) >= :dateFrom1 && UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) <= :dateTo1");
$stmt->execute(array(':dateFrom1' => $_POST[DateFrom1], ':dateTo1' => $_POST[DateTo1]));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Using PDO means you don't have to worry about things such as SQL injection, and it allows for FAR cleaner SQL statements, you don't have to be throwing values from PHP directly into the SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `date` field is of the type `date` or `datetime`, then you *can* do direct comparison without converting to a timestamp.

Also, for your specific case, it looks like you could utilize the *[**expr BETWEEN min AND max**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)* operation, which is equivalent to ***min <= expr AND expr <= max***.

```
$result = "
    SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE date BETWEEN '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['DateFrom1'])) . "'
        AND '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['DateTo1'])) . "'";
```

[**SQLFiddle using type *date***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c1f6e/2)

[**SQLFiddle using type *datetime***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19aa0/1)

---

*Note: if you are storing your dates as a `varchar` datatype or something other than a `date` or `datetime` (or maybe `timestamp`), then you should really consider changing this, in order to take full advantage of MySQL's capabilities.*

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql's UNIX_TIMESTAMP() it may be what you're looking for.